# Calling @Override on paintComponent() when state changes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, overriding

How do I override a paintComponent method with response to a state change? 
Error message: void is an invalid type for the variable paintComponent

```
public class MyContainer extends Container {
public void paintComponent(Graphics m){
    m.drawArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
    m.setColor(Color.green);
    m.fillArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
Container y = new Container();
JFrame x = new JFrame();
JPanel gg = new JPanel();

x.add(y);
x.setTitle("           Shape Changer");
x.setBounds(100,50,500,300);
x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
x.getContentPane().add(new ContentPanel()); 
x.getContentPane().add(new ContnetPanel());
x.setContentPane(new ContnetPanel());
x.setVisible(true);
}

static class ContentPanel extends JPanel{

private Graphics g;
private JPanel ss;
public void paint(Graphics g){
g.drawArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
g.fillRect(100, 100,100,100);
}
public ContentPanel(){

}
}
static class ContnetPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ChangeListener{
    JComboBox comboerbox;
    class appres  {
    public void paint(Graphics h){
        h.drawRect(100,100,100,100);
        h.setColor(Color.red);
        h.fillRect(100,100,100,100);

    }


    }
public ContnetPanel(){
comboerbox = new JComboBox();
comboerbox.addItem("Red Square");
comboerbox.addItem("Blue Square");
comboerbox.addItem("Green Square");
comboerbox.setSelectedIndex(1);
add(comboerbox);
setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics h){
super.paintComponent(h);
h.drawArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
h.setColor(Color.blue);
h.fillArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
repaint();
}
int yy = 0;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
switch(comboerbox.getSelectedIndex()){
case 0:yy=0;

case 1: yy=1;
case 2: yy=2;
}

}
//evt.getSource()==comboerbox
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt){

    if(evt.getSource()==comboerbox){
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics h){
        super.paintComponent(h);
        h.drawArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
        h.setColor(Color.blue);
        h.fillArc(100,100,100,100,100,100);
        repaint();
    }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

 }
 }
 }
```

Of course, the paintComponent method isn't a variable. How would I override paintComponent here? Or is a better way to change the shape with response to state change? That would be great too!
Thanks in advance, love you guys!

Answer (score 1):

In your last question: [How do I make the superclass go beyond just the content pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317119/how-do-i-make-the-superclass-go-beyond-just-the-content-pane) you were given a link to the Swing tutorial for some Swing basics.

Well there is also a section on `Custom Painting` for you to read. You can then download the example and play with it to understand how painting works.

Basically the Container class doesn't have a paintComponent() method so you should not be trying to do custom painting in that class.

If you want to change a painting property, then you need to add a method to your class to change the state of the property and then invoke repaint() on itself.

So from the tutorial example in Step 3 you can see how the `moveSquare(...)` method changes the state of the class and then invokes repaint().

Note you should never invoke repaint() in the paintComponent() method since this will cause the painting to be continually rescheduled.